# jQuery - Ajax request for xml file not showing errors yet I can't fetch its contents

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I have two files in the same directory, **fetch.html** & **other.xml** (so this doesn't appear to be a  CORS issue.) - there are no errors in the console and the network tab shows that I have sucessfully retrieved the xml file.

I try selecting an element from **other.xml** (`$("restaurant")`) in the console and it returns an empty array without any errors. I've cleared cache and renamed the files but nothing is changing. Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

At the bottom of the body in **fetch.html** I have this script:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "other.xml",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Success");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**other.xml** looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<restaurants>
    <restaurant name="Pan Africa Market" address="1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.608940" lng="-122.340141" type="sitdown"/>
    <restaurant name="Buddha Thai &nbsp; Bar" address="2222 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613590" lng="-122.344391" type="bar"/>
    <restaurant name="The Melting Pot" address="14 Mercer St, Seattle, WA" lat="47.624561" lng="-122.356445" type="sitdown"/>
    <restaurant name="Ipanema Grill" address="1225 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.606365" lng="-122.337654" type="sitdown"/>
    <restaurant name="Sake House" address="2230 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.612823" lng="-122.345673" type="bar"/>
    <restaurant name="Crab Pot" address="1301 Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.605961" lng="-122.340363" type="sitdown"/>
    <restaurant name="Mama's Mexican Kitchen" address="2234 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613976" lng="-122.345467" type="bar"/>
    <restaurant name="Wingdome" address="1416 E Olive Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.617214" lng="-122.326584" type="bar"/>
    <restaurant name="Piroshky Piroshky" address="1908 Pike pl, Seattle, WA" lat="47.610126" lng="-122.342834" type="sitdown"/>
</restaurants>
```

Comment: set `dataType : 'xml'` in the ajax function to have the result parsed as XML

Comment: @adeneo: It appears to already be parsed as XML .. but adding that didn't log anything in the console :/

Comment: Try it like this, and tell us what you get -> http://jsfiddle.net/bDj5Y/

Comment: @adeneo: Hmm it still doesn't log "Success" - I put the response in comments below your jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/bDj5Y/1/

Comment: That's a parse error, you don't have valid XML, and that causes issues.

Comment: @adeneo: I thought that would be the problem .. but the XML looks good! I can't find anything wrong with it .. it passes validation as well.

Comment: Doesn't look valid to me, I get errors on entities, such as `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<restaurant name="Buddha Thai &nbsp; <---
```

`&nbsp;` is not a [predefined entity in XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML). You can't use it in a plain XML document. If need `&nbsp;` in your app then you can escape it as `&amp;nbsp;`